# The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, flask, facebook-messenger-bot

Getting this error when I am accessing through Facebook messenger?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Here is code

## webapp

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request,jsonify,
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/prediction', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def prediction():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form != None and 'message' in request.form:
            msg = request.form['message']
            response =  pred(str(msg))
            return jsonify(response) 
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p1>
        Yooooo Tensorflow thoooo
    </p1>
<form action="{{ url_for('prediction') }}" method='POST' >
    <input type=text name="message" value="" maxlength="100">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to run through Facebook messenger which I am connecting using heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both POST and GET are enabled in your view, this is most likely a CORS error

Follow the instructions [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)  to allow cross origin requests for apache

Or [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) if your Web server is nginx

For example, my apps hosted on ubuntu 16.04 using apache, i run

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

on the terminal

I edit my servers configuration and add **Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"**  to allow cross origin requests. The star is a wild card meaning I allow requests from any site, you can replace it with the sites you want to allow

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp.wsgi
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mysite.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysite.com.info
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Ignore the rewrite rules that redirects requests to my app to https. You only need to add **Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"**

Comment: Can you explain bit in details as I don't have good understanding of flask?

Comment: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is not flask specific. [The same-origin security policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) forbids "cross-domain" requests by default (A user agent makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain, protocol, or port than the one from which the current document originated.).  This means that a web application can only request HTTP resources from the same domain the application was loaded from. To allow cross origin resource sharing, you edit your web server configuration as shown in the links shared above

Comment: In this app.py file, we want to create a route (/prediction in my case) where the input to the route will be fed into our saved model, and the decoder output is the string that is returned. This is what I am doing by connecting heroku to facebook messenger webhook.

Comment: My understanding is that the request will come from Facebook messenger to your app. That is already a cross domain request that violates same origin security policy so you will need to edit the server where your app is hosted

Comment: yeah,I have done some mistake in the same line you are talking about and right now it's working I am able to rectify it